How to show this discrete quadratic equation converges?
So I have a discrete process
$V_{k}=AV_{k-1}A^T+C$
where $C$ is a constant and $V$ is symmetric (this is supposed to be the update for the state covariance of a discrete stochastic process). I read that the above converges as $k$ goes to $\infty$ if $A$ has its eigenvalues in the unit disk. How can I show this?
I know that $A^k$ will go to zero as $k$ goes to $\infty$ if its eigenvalues are in the unit disk so I think I can show that the $V$ dependent term goes to zero, but the constant $C$ terms are giving me trouble because there seems to be a summation of an unbounded amount of different $A^n C [A^T]^n$ terms as I consider larger and larger $k$.

Sorry, could you elaborate a bit underflow? I've tried to look into it, and I'm still a bit lost.

@underflow unfortunately I can't seem to do so in a useful manner, since what I obtained seems to grow with larger difference between $k$ and $l$.  Also thank you very much for the assistance.

@underflow Im only examining the summation of $C$ terms since the $V_0$ dependent term goes to $0$ I think. Then, I used the submultiplicative property of operator norms to get that past some $N$, I can be assured that for any $\epsilon>0$ I can get that $||A^d C [A^T]^d||\leq \epsilon$ for all $d\geq N$. So, with $V_k-V_l$ having the summation of $A^d C [A^T]^d$ terms where $d>N$, I used the additive property of matrices operators to get that the operator norm of this summation is bounded by $(k-l)\epsilon$. Sorry, I'm not too good at math so I'm a bit confused as to how to go from here.

@underflow oh so then I can find the bound on the operator norm using a bounding geometric series that is convergent since $a<1$? Thank you, I think I see how I can find the bound on the operator norm of $V_k-V_l$, but how would I use that to imply $V_k$ is convergent?

@underflow oh ha I see. Thank you so much, if you just answer with your first comment and mention the answer is in the comment chain, I would accept your answer.
